# Global choice and skeletons of large categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is stated on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton#equivalents_of_choice) that the axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement that all small categories have a weak skeleton, meaning a skeletal category which is equivalent to them.

> Is the [axiom of global choice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+choice#Variants) in MK equivalent to the statement that all (possibly large) categories have weak skeletons?

Comment: Yes, by the same argument as for small categories - for a family of disjoint nonempty sets form a category whose objects are the union of the family, and each member of the family defines an isomorphism class. A skeleton gives a choice function.

Comment: @Wojowu Very nice, thank you. If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, by the same argument as for small categories and regular choice. First, assuming global choice, you can form skeleta by picking out one element from each isomorphism class of objects.

EDIT: As Sergei Akbarov points out in the comment, the argument is not quite right - to apply global choice we need to apply it to a class of sets, but the collection of isomorphism classes need not consist of just sets (in fact most natural categories don't have this property). One way to salvage this argument is to exploit [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick): replace each isomorphism class $I$, which may be a proper class, with a set $I\cap V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha$ is the least level of the [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) whose intersection with $I$ is nonempty. Thus we have replaced each isomorphism class with its nonempty subset, and we can apply global choice to the resulting class of sets.

---

Conversely, suppose we have a class $F$ of nonempty sets and we want to find a choice function for it. Take a category $C$ whose objects are the disjoint union of elements of $F$, and we have exactly one morphism between any two objects belonging to one element of $F$. Then the sets of $F$ are the isomorphism classes from $C$, and any (weak) skeleton constitutes a choice function for $F$.

Comment: I don't understand something. For picking element from isomorphism classes by applying axiom of choice, these classes of isomorphisms must be elements of some "big class". So they must be sets. Why are they sets? This seems to be not true.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The isomorphism classes don’t have to be members of any other class, they’re just classes consisting of all objects in the category which are isomorphic. If these isomorphism classes are sets you can consider the class of all of them, but if any of them are proper classes (as is guarantees for a large category) you can’t consider a class of all isomorphism classes, only each individual isomorphism class in the wild as subset of the universe (not an element of the universe).

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov This is interpreting global choice as meaning the statement that any nonempty class has a choice function. Note that the formulation of choice referring to a set of nonempty sets isn’t a valid formulation for proper classes, unless you want to consider a collection of them informally in the metalanguage.

Comment: Alec, still, I don't understand something. Are you speaking about the Morse-Kelley set theory?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: First, one must apply [Scott's trick](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Scott's+trick) to form a class of sets that intersect each equivalence class exactly once.  Then one can construct the quotient and invoke the axiom of global choice.

Comment: @AlecRhea: The axiom of global choice states that any surjection of classes splits.  How does it imply your statement?

Comment: Sergei is right, there is a gap in my argument - I was focusing on the other direction so the subtlety of the isomorphism classes being proper-class- rather than set-sized slipped me. I will edit accordingly. While I'm not sure I understand how Dmitri applies it, the use of Scott's trick seems necessary.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I phrased things poorly; I was implicitly thinking in terms of a global [choice operator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/choice+operator), but this is not the standard formulation of global choice (although it is equivalent). I think using a choice operator allows us to carry out the construction in a straightforward manner.

Comment: I remember some time ago here at MO (or maybe at MSE, but I can't find the reference) somebody explained to me that this proposition follows from the possibility to well-order the class of all sets (it seems to me, that was @AndreasBlass, excuse me if this is not so).

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov It can follow from [Scott's trick](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Scott%27s+trick), which in turn follows from the ability to form a well-founded cumulative hierarchy. Alternatively, you could just use the [simple choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385493/a-simple-form-of-choice) axiom to select an element of a class in a straightforward manner, and this is equivalent to standard choice for class theories via the argument outlined in that linked post.